# Data migration with taosdump in TDengine

Tags: tdengine

We have a machine with TDengine 2.0.6.0 installed. We didn't install taosdump tool at first. Now we want to export the data.

I tried to copy the taosdump in 2.0.15.0 to the appropriate directory. Then I encountered an error:

> taosdump:symbol lookup error: taosdump:undefined symbol:taosWriteImp.

How can I configure it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You copied a higher version taosdump, 2.0.15.0, from the error message it realies on some APIs that are not defined in 2.0.6.0 libraries.

It's recommended to upgrade TDengine to same version and install taosdump, not just copy, because there may be some other dependencies you don't know.